# I am getting this error and don't know how to resolve it

Tags: node.js, typescript, calculator

```
index.ts:5:8 - error TS1192: Module '"D:/Calculator/node_modules/@types/chalk-animation/index"' has no default export.

5 import chalkAnimation from "chalk-animation";
         ~~~~~~

index.ts:22:1 - error TS1378: Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.

22 await welcome()
```

I am trying to use inquirer,chalk and chalk animation in node.js .Although my calculator is running on other computer but I don't understand why it is showing this error in my computer

Comment: It says there is no default export, could you check that the module has a default export and that the types file confirms this?

Answer (score 0):

In your tsconfig.json file, under `"compilerOptions"`, add `"esModuleInterop": true`.

```json
{
    ...
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Without [`esModuleInterop`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop), TypeScript defaults to resolving import names with a legacy mechanism, that is not compliant with the ESM spec, and is not compatible with the way Node.js handles imports of CJS modules in new code.

Comment: this is already true